# Average same cell across sheets - exclude zeros/errors

Tags: excel, vba, average

I am trying to find a way to do averages of the same cell across multiple sheets that excludes zeros and errors.

Notes:

There are 3 sheets at the beginning of the workbook which are not included in this calculation.

I have a form which creates new sheets and adds them to the current AVERAGE formula.

The formula at this point looks like this:

```
=AVERAGE('Book Title 1'!I11,'Book Title 2'!I11,'Book Title 3!I11,'Book Title 4'!I11)
```

Here is the script which creates the sheets from form data and updates the formulas on my Stats sheet when a book is added...

```
 Public strBookName As String, txAuthor As String, txPublisher As String, txRate As String, txWords As String, txPages As String, txHours As String, txRatio As String, txDays As String, aveHours As String, aveRatio As String, BookTitle As String


Sub btnAdd_Click()
    
    Dim strFormula As String, tabColor As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    strBookName = ""
    txAuthor = ""
    txPublisher = ""
    txRate = ""
    txWords = ""
    txPages = ""
    txHours = ""
    txRatio = ""
    txDays = ""
        
    aveHours = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STATS").Range("G10").Value
    aveRatio = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STATS").Range("G19").Value
    tabColor = Int((56 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    frmAddBook.Show
        
    If Len(strBookName) <> 0 Then
        'Add the sheet...
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("TEMPLATE")
        ActiveSheet.Name = strBookName
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2) = strBookName
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2) = txAuthor
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2) = txPublisher
        ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2) = txRate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 2) = txWords
        ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 2) = txPages
        'ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 2) = txHours
        'ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 2) = txRatio
        ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 2) = txDays
        
              If Len(aveHours) <> 0 Then
                   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strBookName).Range("B9").Value = aveHours
                   
                   Else
                   
                   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strBookName).Range("B9").Value = txHours
                   
                   End If
        
                If Len(aveRatio) <> 0 Then
                   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strBookName).Range("B10").Value = aveRatio
                   
                   Else
                   
                   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strBookName).Range("B10").Value = txRatio
                   
                   End If
        
        ActiveSheet.Cells(25, 1).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 2
                 
               
    End If
    
   Call UpdateStats

End Sub


Sub UpdateStats()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, nm, arrSkip, frm, sep
    
    arrSkip = Array("TEMPLATE", "STATS", "INSTRUCTIONS") 'add other sheet here
    
    frm = ""
    sep = ""
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        nm = ws.Name
        'check name before processing
        If IsError(Application.Match(nm, arrSkip, 0)) Then
            frm = frm & sep & "'" & nm & "'!<C>"
            sep = ","
        End If
    Next ws
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("STATS")
        If Len(frm) > 0 Then 'any sheets to summarize?
            .Cells(11, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "E2") & ")"
            .Cells(12, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "E3") & ")"
            .Cells(13, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "E4") & ")"
            .Cells(14, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "E5") & ")"
            .Cells(15, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "E6") & ")"
            .Cells(22, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I18") & ")"
            .Cells(24, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I20") & ")"
            

            .Cells(10, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I2") & ")"
            .Cells(11, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I3") & ")"
            .Cells(12, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I4") & ")"
            .Cells(13, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I5") & ")"
            .Cells(14, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I6") & ")"
            .Cells(15, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I7") & ")"
            .Cells(16, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I8") & ")"
            .Cells(17, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I9") & ")"
            .Cells(18, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I10") & ")"
            .Cells(19, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I11") & ")"
            .Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "E6") & ")"

        Else
            Range("C11:C15").ClearContents
            Range("C22").ClearContents
            Range("C24").ClearContents
            Range("G10:G19").ClearContents
            Range("G21").ClearContents
            Range("G24").ClearContents
        End If
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

So, I need to continue to be able to update the stats data as new sheets are added, while ignoring any zeros or errors (since some of the stats are built from formulas on the new sheets which throw errors until data is entered.)

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I'm not sure what you edited. Could you explain? Was it an answer or something else?

Comment: I formatted the code. Nothing else.

Comment: Please explain what problem does your code have

Comment: This code doesn't technically have any 'problem' per se. It works perfectly fine. I just want to change it so that it does what I asked in my original post.

I need to get the parts that calculate AVERAGE to ignore any fields that have either a 0 or an error (from incomplete data when I first create a new sheet but haven't entered any data yet.)

Since it's averaging individuals cells but across multiple sheets, I cannot use the AVERAGEIF function.

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question and add some sample data and screenshots of the formula would help

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I do have an example formula in my question and the code has the script which creates that formula currently. 

Many of the cells for which it's pulling data are using formulas themselves which populate as data is entered in the sheet. This is why I'm trying to figure out how to create a way to average those cells and ignore any errors or zeros.